# Got a PDF virus on my Mac, and Preview tried to view it: have I been infected?

Tags: macos, pdf, virus, malware

Today I got some malware in my email: an empty mail with a PDF attachment. I tried saving the Pdf in order to upload it to virustotal.com and have it analyzed... but the problem is that, since I'm on a Mac (OS X 10.11):

1. When I opened the email, the Mail program tried to show a preview of the file.
2. When I picked the PDF using the file selection dialog to upload it, Preview tried to load it and show a preview.

The PDF in question was indeed malware, BTW, according to Virustotal. It is here:

https://www.virustotal.com/es/file/d9b28ac083698cc529653e0108a37f2343dfc6e61e51373ff0c2c88d158cdbe5/analysis/

So, according to the information there, have I been infected just by Preview's attempt to show me the file? Without even actually "opening" it?

EDIT: to be clear, I did "open" the file with Preview. But the Virustotal page seems to suggest that it's a MS Office trojan, and yet, its "Details" tab says that it seems to use embedded Javascript code, not Office macros. So, could I have been infected just by opening it with Preview? Can anyone who has encountered this virus share some info about its behavior?

Comment: Well you did open it. How do you think a preview is created without reading the file?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so :-). But my question is: some of the info in Virustotal seem to say that this malware targets MS Office, but other pieces of info say that it executes JS. So, if I have "opened" only with Apple's Preview and not with Office, does the malware work? Has anyone else found this piece of malware and know something more about its behavior?

Comment: This virus a Windows virus or a MacOS virus?  If it's a MacOS then it possible, and you should assume, your system was infected

Comment: The Virustotal page has the info. It is detected by several AVs as "Vba.Gen!c", "Trojan[Downloader]/MSWord.Agent.bgy", etc. The closest I've been able to find is an AV that detects it as "Doc.Dropper.Dridex-6260340-0" and this page: http://blog.talosintelligence.com/2017/04/threat-round-up-0407-0414.html, which says that it is an Office trojan. (And yet, the email I received was  a PDF file).

Comment: It looks as if it were a Windows virus, which would have a very hard time to be executed on Mac. Also, as you opened the file in Preview.app, you are insofar lucky because Preview.app is too dumb to execute any JavaScript (and, unless the JavaScript were Acrobat JavaScript, even if it could, it would not be properly interpreted).